# Expect script execution status

Tags: linux, ssh, expect

In the following expect script how to  get the exit status of rsync in the expect script
`if [$? -eq 0]`  throws an error as

```
         invalid command name "$?"
         while executing
         "$? -eq 0 "
         invoked from within
        "if [ $? -eq 0 ]"
       (file "./tmp544.sh" line 7)


    #!/usr/bin/expect -f

    eval spawn ssh -l root 174.54.87.12 rsync /root/project /usr/project
    expect "root@174.54.87.12's password: $"
    send "\xxxxxxx\n"
    expect "\\$ $"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo "11"
    else
      echo "22"
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if [$? -eq 0]
```

is a shell construction, and you are in an expect script.
I think you should separate the rsync part from the ssh part, and use the remote shell to evaluate rsync status :

```
eval spawn ssh -l root 174.54.87.12
expect "root@174.54.87.12's password: $"
send "\xxxxxxx\n"
expect "\\$ $"
send "rsync /root/project /usr/project"
expect "\\$ $"
send "echo $?"
# Examine the output of $?
```

$? is available on interactive shell, not only in scripts, you can use it on the command line, and it looks like a good occasion to do so !

I am not familiar with expect, but I guess expect "\$ $" is waiting for the shell prompt, so I blindly copy pasted it.

Comment: expect {\$ $} is an arguably more idiomatic alternative to expect "\\$ $"